# Type A is not equal to type A in Haskell (ghci interpreter)?

Tags: haskell, types, shadowing

GHCi is telling me that type `A` is not type `A`. Why?

```
>>> data A = A
>>> let x = A
>>> let id A = A
>>> 
>>> data A = A
>>> let x' = A
>>> let id' A = A
>>> 
>>> data A = A
>>>
>>> let y = id' x

<interactive>:18:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `main::Interactive.A'
                with actual type `main::Interactive.A'
    In the first argument of id', namely `x'
    In the expression: id' x
    In an equation for `y': y = id' x
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GHCi has some odd behaviors when dealing with scoping, here's a shorter session that clearly demonstrates this:

```
Prelude> data A = A
Prelude> let meh A = A
Prelude> data A = A
Prelude> meh A

<interactive>:5:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `main::Interactive.A'
            with actual type `A'
    In the first argument of `meh', namely `A'
    In the expression: meh A
    In an equation for `it': it = meh A
```

As far as GHCi's concerned, you might as well have done this:

```
Prelude> data A = A
Prelude> let meh A = A
Prelude> data A' = A'
Prelude> meh A'

<interactive>:5:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `A' with actual type A'
    In the first argument of `meh', namely A'
    In the expression: meh A'
    In an equation for `it': it = meh A'
```

It sees it as totally different data types, it's just that they have the same name.

You can read all about it [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html). The relevant section is 2.4.4.

Comment: It's not really the scoping behavior that's odd. It's exactly the same as the behavior for variables and the only choice that makes sense since the second declaration may not be compatible with the first. The problem is that they look the same in error messages.

Comment: @hammar maybe counter intuitive error msgs would have been better phrased,

Comment: @jozefg: It's still wrong. It should look like this: http://pastebin.com/Thitf7Qd

Comment: @Dog Not on my version of ghc, and youre missing the point, the actual text of the error message is kinda beside the point...

Comment: @jozefg: It would then seem that your GHCi is nondeterministically choosing when to prefix the type name with `main::Interactive.`, you should report a bug to your distro, could be corrupt memory. The error message in my post is the whole point, it's saying `A/=A`.

Comment: @Dog: Did it occur to you that this might just differ between versions of GHC? Corrupt memory is most definitely *not* the reason. What would be a "good" message in your opinion? After all, both types *are* called `A`. This question is hilarious.

Comment: @NiklasB., 1) No, it did not occur to me, because he clearly modified the output by hand, making it hard to follow his answer. 2) I highly doubt any version of GHC outputs what he had wrote before.

Comment: @Dog: It seems to me like you are just nitpicking here, thereby wasting everyones time. What's more, this doesn't seem to be your first question of this type. I consider this quite rude, to say the least.

Comment: @NiklasB., I was just pointing out that he should post the correct output so other readers don't have to scratch their heads as much, and unfortunately he argued instead of just rerunning his code and finding out that what he wrote by hand is not the real result. Get over yourself. I understand he didn't intend (or realize) that he posted false information, but false information is what wastes people's time. Next time I'll just edit the answer directly to spare unnecessary discussion like this.

Comment: @Dog: Yes, *please* do that the next time. This is exactly what the editing functionality is for.